# clojure titanium - How to save to berkely DB?

Tags: clojure, titanium, berkeley-db-je, titan

I can read and add stuff to a titanium graph (using berkely DB backend) e.g. the following:

```
(let [g (tg/open "/tmp/mygraph")]
```

I can then use

```
(tg/add-vertex g ...
```

to modify the graph.
But how do I save the modified graph to my berkleydb backend?

I have no properties file for titan and I am using [clojurewerkz/titanium "1.0.0-alpha1"]

Answer (score 1):

Titan resolves and persists all changes when the [current transaction is committed](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Transaction-Handling). In Titanium, transaction control functions are [available in master](https://github.com/clojurewerkz/titanium/blob/master/ChangeLog.md#transaction-control-functions) and will be soon released with alpha2.

Update: [alpha2 is released](http://blog.clojurewerkz.org/blog/2013/02/25/titanium-1-dot-0-0-alpha2-is-released/), [documentation](http://titanium.clojurewerkz.org) is updated to cover transaction control.